# How to display menu items in a horizontal line using ASP.NET Menu control?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET web application, and I'm using the Menu control to create a navigation bar. However, I'm facing an issue with displaying the menu items in a horizontal line. Currently, the menu items are displayed vertically like a list.

I want to achieve the following layout for my menu:

Narudžbe | Artikli | Prijevoznici | Kupci | Izvještaji

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="LandingPage.aspx.vb" Inherits="Mišković_OMIS_projekt.LandingPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .navbar {
            background-color: #333;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center; /* Align items horizontally */
        }

        .navbar a {
            float: none; /* Remove float property */
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .navbar a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }

        .logo {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px 0;
        }

        .logo img {
            width: 800px; /* Adjust the width as per your logo's dimensions */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="navbar">
            <asp:Menu ID="MyMenu" runat="server">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Narudžbe" Value="~/Stranice/Narudzbe.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Artikli" Value="~/Stranice/Artikli.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Prijevoznici" Value="~/Stranice/Prijevoznici.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Kupci" Value="~/Stranice/Kupci.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Izvještaji" Value="~/Stranice/Izvjestaji.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="Images/logo.png" alt="OMIS Logo" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried modifying the CSS properties such as display: flex and float: none, but the menu items are still displayed in a vertical list. How can I modify my CSS or ASP.NET code to achieve the desired horizontal layout for the menu items?

Here is also the code-behind in VB.NET:

```
Public Class LandingPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        MyMenu.Items(0).NavigateUrl = "~/Stranice/Narudzbe.aspx"
        MyMenu.Items(1).NavigateUrl = "~/Stranice/Artikli.aspx"
        MyMenu.Items(2).NavigateUrl = "~/Stranice/Prijevoznici.aspx"
        MyMenu.Items(3).NavigateUrl = "~/Stranice/Kupci.aspx"
        MyMenu.Items(4).NavigateUrl = "~/Stranice/Izvjestaji.aspx"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub MyMenu_MenuItemClick(sender As Object, e As MenuEventArgs) Handles MyMenu.MenuItemClick
        ' Get the selected item's URL
        Dim selectedItemUrl As String = MyMenu.SelectedItem.Value

        ' Redirect to the selected page
        Response.Redirect(selectedItemUrl)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the menu settings:

[image]

if you set above in property sheet, then your menu becomes this:

```
        <asp:Menu ID="MyMenu" runat="server" 
            Orientation="Horizontal" RenderingMode="Table">
            <Items>
```

And the result is this:

[image]